# resignFirstResponder and - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {return NO;} isnt hiding the keyboard, why isnt it working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I want the keyboard to disappear when the user presses the "return" button, but I have tried `resignFirstResponder`, `endEditing:YES` and - 
`(BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {return NO;}`and the keyboard still didn't disappear. What should I do?

Here's the relevant code: (everything else is empty (viewDidLoad is empty, etc.)

```
@implementation ViewController {
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
    //[self.view endEditing:YES]; (I uncommented this out and tested it)
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: plz check your delegate you confirm or not?

Comment: @balkaran Oh... ya... It works now that I've set the delegate... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

plz confirm your UITextField Delegate From Storyboard or set

```
textfield.delegate = self;
```

in - (void)viewDidLoad

and use the methode

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```